# Add custom Product

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, product

I am newbie to magento . I want to add a custom product So that user can add it to cart. The product would be customer's. Other than a particular customer, no one can buy it. so I will have to store user id with product details. Is it Possible? If it is, In which table should I store the product details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in magento you can associate product catagories to a particular customer or even group of customers (General, wholesale,retailer) i.e Show particular category products to particular customers and customer groups only.
But for this you need to extend the existing functionality of magento by creating a custom module.

In order to store the product details for a particular customer you can create a table which will have the association of both categories and customers.

For customer details we have `customer_entity` and `customer_entity_varchar` tables and for categories we have `catalog_category_entity`.

You can take association of these tables in your custom table.

Comment: I would recommend adding more information if you have to improve the quality of the answer and be further helpful to the person who asked question

Comment: So, Do I have to create different categories for different users? @Magikcommerce

Comment: No, you dont have to create diffrent categories to diffrent users. for eg : if you have category ABC and it has a product X and you have a customer of yours Mr.A.Then if you want products under category ABC can only be purchased by Mr.A then you have to associate that particular category to customer Mr.A. And you can do this by creating a grid view under customers tab in admin which will show all the categories of your store.Then you can associate that particular category from list of categories provided and then check on frontend.